# What's Escanor's power level when he's in the one mode?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Before reaching the one mode, in the battle with Meliodas Escanor's power level is said to be 114,000 and Meliodas 142,000. But when he reachs "the one", he can defeat Meliodas and he's said to be "invincible". What's Escanor's power level when he's in the one mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/NanatsunoTaizai/comments/4xtk6x/spoiler_escanors_power_level/) made an attempt, based on various statements from the manga

> - 216015 total power at noon. (6,64 times of Meliodas last stated power of 32500, 3,54 times of Zeldris power of 61000, 3,6 times of Estarossa power of 60000)
> - 108015 total power at noon. (3,32 times of Meliodas last stated power of 32500, 1,77 times of Zeldris power of 61000, times 1,8 of Estarossa power of 60000)

There appears to be no official canon on Escanor's power at high noon